# Azure AD Pass-through Authentication on Federated environment

Tags: azure

I would like to be able to Azure AD join machines.

My environment is Federated with SAML2 identity provider Internet2 Shibboleth (that does not implement WS-Fed or WS-Trust).

Is it doable to deploy a Pass-through Authentication througth Azure Authentication Agents to allow Azure AD join and Windows logon from joined devices while at the same time doing web authentication (like on https://www.office.com for example) with Internet2 Shibboleth as we are doing now?

Comment: Hmm... I'm unable to understand the relation between "Pass-through Authentication (PTA)" and login from joined devices, PTA is only used to 1) offload authentication from the cloud to happen on your local domain and 2) to replace ADFS if you have that, you only need the devices to be joined to the Azure AD tenant so they can have a "Primary Refresh Token (PRT)" which will enable SSO for those devices, this shouldn't effect your Shibboleth setup... to my knowledge...

Comment: Not sure to know enough about this scenario to be able to explain properly. The objective is to have laptops not joined to On-Premise AD where users can login with their Active Directory work or school accounts. And I would like not to scrap Shibboleth if possibile.

Comment: In that case, there's a lot to cover based in your current setup, highly recommend to start by reading this doc: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/azureadjoin-plan

Comment: I gave the document another read, it looks like you'll need to configure PTA or PHS to enable SSO: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/hybrid-azuread-join-managed-domains#configure-seamless-sso, mind me asking why you're dependent on Shibboleth instead of just using AAD?

Comment: Shibboleth works for all the other (not Microsoft-)istitutional logins. It is good to have a single form for all services. When we setup the trust between our institution and AD (5 or 6 years ago) we focused on web access to O365 which is possible with Shibboleth.